# How to use string directive extractor in a nested route in Spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

Answering my own question here because this took me over a day to figure out and it was a really simple gotcha that I think others might run into.

While working on a RESTful-esk service I'm creating using spray, I wanted to match routes that had an alphanumeric id as part of the path. This is what I originally started out with:

```
case class APIPagination(val page: Option[Int], val perPage: Option[Int])
get {
  pathPrefix("v0" / "things") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      parameters('page ? 0, 'perPage ? 10).as(APIPagination) { pagination =>
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete("things")
        }
      }
    } ~ 
    path(Segment) { thingStringId =>
      pathEnd {
        complete(thingStringId)
      } ~
      pathSuffix("subthings") {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          complete("subthings")
        }
      } ~
      pathSuffix("othersubthings") {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          complete("othersubthings")
        }
      } 
    }
  }
} ~ //more routes...
```

And this has no issue compiling, however when using scalatest to verify that the routing structure is correct, I was surprised to find this type of output:

```
"ThingServiceTests:"
"Thing Service Routes should not reject:"
- should /v0/things
- should /v0/things/thingId
- should /v0/things/thingId/subthings *** FAILED ***
  Request was not handled (RouteTest.scala:64)
- should /v0/things/thingId/othersubthings *** FAILED ***
  Request was not handled (RouteTest.scala:64)
```

What's wrong with my route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at a number of resources, [like this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689077/how-to-structure-a-restful-api-with-spray-io) and [this blog post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/first-steps-with-rest-spray-and-scala.html) but couldn't seem to find anything about using string Id's as a toplevel part of a route structure. I looked through the [spray scaladoc](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.routing.package) as well as beat my head against the [documentation on Path matchers for a while](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/path-directives/pathmatcher-dsl/) before spotting [this important test (duplicated below)](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/ccc3f20477a0752233f19315dcbf695050c399ab/spray-routing-tests/src/test/scala/spray/routing/PathDirectivesSpec.scala#L140):

```
"pathPrefix(Segment)" should {
    val test = testFor(pathPrefix(Segment) { echoCaptureAndUnmatchedPath })
    "accept [/abc]" in test("abc:")
    "accept [/abc/]" in test("abc:/")
    "accept [/abc/def]" in test("abc:/def")
    "reject [/]" in test()
  }
```

This tipped me off to a couple things. That I should try out using `pathPrefix` instead of `path`. So I changed my route to look like this:

```
get {
  pathPrefix("v0" / "things") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      parameters('page ? 0, 'perPage ? 10).as(APIPagination) { pagination =>
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          listThings(pagination)
        }
      }
    } ~ 
    pathPrefix(Segment) { thingStringId =>
      pathEnd {
        showThing(thingStringId)
      } ~
      pathPrefix("subthings") {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          listSubThingsForMasterThing(thingStringId)
        }
      } ~
      pathPrefix("othersubthings") {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          listOtherSubThingsForMasterThing(thingStringId)
        }
      } 
    }
  }
} ~
```

And was happy to get all my tests passing and the route structure working properly. then I update it to use a `Regex` matcher instead:

```
pathPrefix(new scala.util.matching.Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) { thingStringId =>
```

and decided to post on SO for anyone else who runs into a similar issue. As jrudolph points out in the comments, this is because `Segment` is expecting to match `<Segment><PathEnd>` and not to be used in the middle of a path. Which is what `pathPrefix` is more useful for

Comment: If `Segment` would match literal slashes it would be a bug. What you probably experienced is that `path(Segment)` will only match `/<someSegment><PathEnd>`, i.e. a single segment at the end. You need to use `pathPrefix(Segment)` if you want to match a single segment in the middle of the path. The test you quote shows that everything is working as expected: in each of those examples only `abc` is extracted and the rest of the path remains in the `unmatchedPath`.

Comment: Or explaining it with your own example: `/v0/things/thingId/subthings` failed to match because `path(Segment)` already expected the end of the path after `thingId` not because it consumed all of the path.

Comment: It would be good if the documentation on spray's website was explicit about matching `<somesegment><pathend>` because it is not obvious at all that you need to use pathPrefix and not path. Or at least it wasn't to me.

Comment: @jrudolph I've updated the answer, did I describe the reasoning well? I would like to make sure that other people aren't bit by this (feel free to edit it yourself if you can)

Comment: Almost correct :) Actually, `<PathEnd>` is matched by `path`. `path(x)` matches `<slash><x><PathEnd>` while `pathPrefix(x)` only matches `<slash><x>`.

Comment: Btw. by using `pathSuffix` you now match more than needed. E.g. `/v0/things/<thingId>/abc/def/ghi/subthings` will now be matched as well. The basic rule is: use `pathPrefix` for all outer matching and `path`, `pathEnd`, `pathSingleSlash`, or `pathEndOrSingleSlash` only for the most nested ones.

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph about the `pathSuffix`. I've updated the code.