# Spray route get response from child actor

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am trying to figure out how I can setup a Master Actor that calls the appropriate children, in support of some spray routes where I am trying to emulate db calls.  I am new to akka / spray, so just trying to gain a better understanding of how you would properly setup spray -> actors -> db calls (etc.).  I can get the response back from the top level actor, but when I try to get it back from one actor level below the parent I can't seem to get anything to work.

When looking at the paths of the actors, it appears that from the way I am making the call from my spray route that I am passing from a temp actor. Below is what I have so far for stubbing this out. This has to be just user error / ignorance, just not sure how to proceed.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The Demo Spray Service and Redis Actor code snippets below show where I am calling the actor from my route and the multiple actors where I am having the issue (want my route to get response from SummaryActor). Thanks!

**Boot:**

```
object Boot extends App {

  // we need an ActorSystem to host our application in
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("on-spray-can")

  // create and start our service actor
  val service = system.actorOf(Props[DemoServiceActor], "demo-service")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
  // start a new HTTP server on port 8080 with our service actor as the handler
  IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
}
```

**Demo Service Actor (For Spray)**

```
class DemoServiceActor extends Actor with Api {

  // the HttpService trait defines only one abstract member, which
  // connects the services environment to the enclosing actor or test
  def actorRefFactory = context

  // this actor only runs our route, but you could add
  // other things here, like request stream processing
  // or timeout handling
  def receive = handleTimeouts orElse runRoute(route)

  //Used to watch for request timeouts
  //http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/timeout-handling/
  def handleTimeouts: Receive = {
    case Timedout(x: HttpRequest) =>
      sender ! HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "Too late")
  }


}

//Master trait for handling large APIs
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653526/can-spray-io-routes-be-split-into-multiple-controllers
trait Api extends DemoService {
  val route = {
    messageApiRouting
  }
}
```

**Demo Spray Service (Route):**

```
trait DemoService extends HttpService with Actor  {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds) // needed for `?` below
  val redisActor = context.actorOf(Props[RedisActor], "redisactor")

  val messageApiRouting =
        path("summary" / Segment / Segment) { (dataset, timeslice) =>
          onComplete(getSummary(redisActor, dataset, timeslice)) {
            case Success(value) => complete(s"The result was $value")
            case Failure(ex) => complete(s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
          }
        }

  def getSummary(redisActor: ActorRef, dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[String] = Future {

    val dbMessage = DbMessage("summary", dataset + timeslice)
    val future = redisActor ? dbMessage
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
    result
  }

}
```

**Redis Actor (Mock no actual redis client yet)**

```
class RedisActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  //  val pool = REDIS
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds) // needed for `?` below
  val summaryActor = context.actorOf(Props[SummaryActor], "summaryactor")


  def receive = {

    case msg: DbMessage => {
      msg.query match {
        case "summary" => {
          log.debug("Summary Query Request")
          log.debug(sender.path.toString)
           summaryActor ! msg
        }
      }
    }

    //If not match log an error
    case _ => log.error("Received unknown message: {} ")
  }
}

class SummaryActor extends Actor with ActorLogging{

  def receive = {
    case msg: DbMessage =>{
      log.debug("Summary Actor Received Message")
      //Send back to Spray Route

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you need to forward from the master actor to the child so that the `sender` is properly propagated and available for the child to respond to.  So change this (in `RedisActor`):

```
summaryActor ! msg
```

To:

```
summaryActor forward msg
```

That's the primary issue.  Fix that and your code should start working.  There is something else that needs attention though.  Your `getSummary` method is currently defined as:

```
def getSummary(redisActor: ActorRef, dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[String] = 
  Future {
    val dbMessage = DbMessage("summary", dataset + timeslice)
    val future = redisActor ? dbMessage
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
    result
  }
```

The issue here is that the `ask` operation (`?`) already returns a `Future`, so there and you are blocking on it to get the result, wrapping that in another `Future` so that you can return a `Future` for `onComplete` to work with.  You should be able to simplify things by using the `Future` returned from `ask` directly like so:

```
def getSummary(redisActor: ActorRef, dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[String] = {
  val dbMessage = DbMessage("summary", dataset + timeslice)
  (redisActor ? dbMessage).mapTo[String]      
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. I will take a look at the suggested updates. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm on both accounts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just an important comment on the above approaches.

Since the getSummary(...) function returns a Future[String] object and you call it in onComplete(...) function you need to import:

import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

That way you will have ExecutionContext in scope by letting Future 
declare an implicit ExecutionContext parameter.

** If you don't, you will end up getting a mismatching error 
   since onComplete(...) expects an onComplete Future
   magnet Object but you gave a Future[String] Object.